# ExtJs4 Problem in BoxSelect(Multiselect combobox)

Tags: extjs4

I downloaded the code given in http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134751-Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect-Intuitive-Multi-Select-ComboBox but its not working properly as I try to enter another item by typing. As it gives me error shown below.

ext.fly(node) is null..

Plzz help me into this

Comment: I have   doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)