# Extjs4:Multiselect Option

Tags: extjs4

In my form,i have a list of employees in a combo box and i need to map some employees to particular department.I need to change the combo-box to List box.Scenario is as follows,

```
 1. List A contains all employees.
 2. If i click 'Add' button the selected employees must move to list  B
    and list A must contain remaining employees
```

.

**I searched for List box but i couldn't find in extjs4.**

Is there any example or link for multiselect listbox in ext-js4?

Thanks

Comment: please ref this Question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491175/extjs4-problem-in-boxselectmultiselect-combobox

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in ListBox widget in ExtJs4. However, [Ext.view.View](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.View) may become an listbox after some manipulations.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/molecule-man/ExtJsListbox) of such a tuned `View`. Demos may be found [here](http://molecule-man.github.com/ExtJsListbox/demos/simple.html), [here](http://molecule-man.github.com/ExtJsListbox/demos/panel.html) and [here](http://molecule-man.github.com/ExtJsListbox/demos/advanced.html) (this one looks like just what you need).

You can create two such listboxes and the "add" button. Then assign handler to button which would remove selected item from the first listbox's store and add it to the second's store.